# How do I get input values and set it to state on click and console log it for react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get the user inputs on click and set it to the state to try and display it on console but every time the button is clicked, the state properties are just empty.

For example.
[This is what I want to see in console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFIdK.png)

but I just get:
[Empty state properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAofD.png)

Here is my code

```
  class WalkInBook extends Component {
    constructor(props)
    {
      super(props);
      this.state={
        firstName:'',
        lastName:'',
        phone:'',
        email:'',
        course:'',

      };
    }

    handleClick = () =>
    {
      console.log(this.state);
    }

    handleChangeText(event){
      const target = event.target;
      const value = target.value;
      const name = target.name;

      this.setState({
        [name]:value
      })
    }

    
    

    render() {

      console.log(this.state); 
      //
    // MATERIAL-UI REQUIREMENT #2: Needed for accessing "styles" CB function declared above this class.
    const { classes } = this.props;
      return (
        <div align="center">
           <Typography>
           <div>
             <div className={classes.root} noValidate autoComplete="off">
            <TextField onChangeText={this.handleChangeText} id="standard-basic" name="firstName" label="First Name" />
             </div>
             <div className={classes.root} noValidate autoComplete="off">
               <h1>{this.state.data}</h1>
            <TextField id="standard-basic" name="lastName" label="Last Name" />
             </div>
            <div className={classes.root} noValidate autoComplete="off">
            <TextField  id="standard-basic" name="phone"  label="Phone" />
            </div>
            <div className={classes.root} noValidate autoComplete="off">
            <TextField  id="standard-basic" name="email" label="Email" />
            </div>
            <div className={classes.root} noValidate autoComplete="off">
            <TextField  id="standard-basic" name="course"  label="Course" />
            </div>
           </div>
           <div className={classes.root} noValidate autoComplete="off">
           <Button type="submit" onClick={this.handleClick} variant="outlined">Submit</Button>
           </div>
            </Typography>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: what is the code for the `TextField`?

Comment: those are just from Material ui library
`import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';`

Comment: problem is with context `this`. Try changing the handler to an arrow function `handleChangeText = (event) => { .... }`

Comment: i've also tried that before, but it doesnt work, sadly..

Comment: you need to add an `onChange` prop to your all of your `TextField` components. `<TextField onChange={this.handleChangeText} />`. You also need to either change your `handleChangeText` method to an arrow function or bind it in your constructor.

Comment: that worked for me, thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodePen demo: https://codepen.io/Alexander9111/pen/OJVyRvm

With all code necessary to demonstrate what was asked:

```
class WalkInBook extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      firstName:'',
      lastName:'',
      phone:'',
      email:'',
      course:''
    };
    //These lines are important!
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.handleChangeText = this.handleChangeText.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    
  }

  handleClick() {
    console.log(this.state);
  }

  handleChangeText(event){
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.value;
    const name = target.name;
    console.log('change', name, value);
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      [name] : value
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChangeText} name="firstName" placeholder="firstName"/>
          <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChangeText} name="lastName" placeholder="lastName"/>
          <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChangeText} name="phone" placeholder="phone"/>
          <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChangeText} name="email" placeholder="email"/>
          <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChangeText} name="course" placeholder="course"/>
          <button type="submit" onClick={this.handleClick} variant="outlined">Submit</button>
        </div>
        );
    }
} 

ReactDOM.render(
  <WalkInBook />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

You need to bind this i.e. `.bind(this)` to your onChange onClick event handlers.

Also, you need to use the spread operator to make a copy of your existing state and then modify your one new property:

```
this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      [name] : value
    })
```

**And if you wanted to do it with a functional component** And also iterate over the state to generate the input tags then look at this (https://codepen.io/Alexander9111/pen/VwLPKvP):

```
function WalkInBook(props) {
  const initState = {
      firstName:'',
      lastName:'',
      phone:'',
      email:'',
      course:''
    };
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(initState);

  function handleClick() {
    console.log(state);
  }

  function handleChangeText(event){
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.value;
    const name = target.name;
    console.log('change', name, value);
    setState({
      ...state,
      [name] : value
    })
  }
  
  const handle = handleChangeText;
  const output = Object.keys(state).map(function (key) {
    //console.log(key)
    return <input type="text" onChange={handle} name={key} placeholder={key}/>;
  });
      
  return (
    <div>
      {
        output.map((child, index) => {return child})
      }          
      <button type="submit" onClick={handleClick} variant="outlined">Submit</button>
    </div>
  );
} 

ReactDOM.render(
  <WalkInBook />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code. Please have a look below:

```js
class WalkInBook extends Component {
    constructor(props)
    {
      super(props);
      this.state={
        firstName:'',
        lastName:'',
        phone:'',
        email:'',
        course:'',

      };
    }

    handleClick = () => {
      console.log(this.state);
    }

    handleChangeText = (event) => {
      const { target:{ value, name } } = event
      this.setState({ [name]:value });
    }

    render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
      return (
        <div align="center">
           <Typography>
           <div>
             <div className={classes.root} noValidate autoComplete="off">
            <TextField onChangeText={(e) => this.handleChangeText(e)} id="standard-basic" name="firstName" label="First Name" />
             </div>
             <div className={classes.root} noValidate autoComplete="off">
               <h1>{this.state.data}</h1>
            <TextField onChangeText={(e) => this.handleChangeText(e)} id="standard-basic" name="lastName" label="Last Name" />
             </div>
            <div className={classes.root} noValidate autoComplete="off">
            <TextField onChangeText={(e) => this.handleChangeText(e)}  id="standard-basic" name="phone"  label="Phone" />
            </div>
            <div className={classes.root} noValidate autoComplete="off">
            <TextField onChangeText={(e) => this.handleChangeText(e)}  id="standard-basic" name="email" label="Email" />
            </div>
            <div className={classes.root} noValidate autoComplete="off">
            <TextField onChangeText={(e) => this.handleChangeText(e)}  id="standard-basic" name="course"  label="Course" />
            </div>
           </div>
           <div className={classes.root} noValidate autoComplete="off">
           <Button type="submit" onClick={this.handleClick} variant="outlined">Submit</Button>
           </div>
            </Typography>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```